# Can a community user create Account in community page?

Tags: community

want to create account in community page when a community user logged into community.I am not able to create account record and cant see account tab also when logged in as community user into community.

Comment: Things have changed since 2014. Community Users who have the Customer Community Plus license are allowed to create accounts.

Answer (score 6):

That's a limitation of the Communities license. Accounts are Read-Only from within a Communities portal. See [this reference](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm) for the limitations of Communities licenses.